# PostgreSQL, can't set default value using ALTER COLUMN SET DEFAULT

Tags: postgresql

I want to set default value for already existed column of `INTEGER` type in table.

According to the [postgreSQL doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html) I should use the following statement:

```
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name SET DEFAULT expression
```

Therefore my sql statement looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN board_consecutive_share_days SET DEFAULT 0;
```

After I issued the command nothing happened, the default value was't set to the column:

```
ownpleasuretestdb=# select board_consecutive_share_days from users; 

 board_consecutive_share_days 
------------------------------



(3 rows)
```

So, please tell me what is wrong in my sql statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set the default for the column. That means, whenever you `INSERT` a new row into that table, if you omit that column, the default value will be used.

For example, if you create a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (a int, b int default 0);
```

Then you can issue:

```
# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 2);
# INSERT INTO foo (a) VALUES (2);
# SELECT * FROM foo;
---+---
 1 | 2
 2 | 0
(2 rows)
```

If, on the other hand, you want to set all existing values to 0, then you can do that with an `UPDATE` statement. Something like this would work:

```
UPDATE users SET board_consecutive_share_days = 0;
```

If you only want to set that value where there is no value yet (that is, where it's `null`), that's easy, too:

```
UPDATE users SET board_consecutive_share_days = 0 WHERE board_consecutive_share_days IS NULL;
```